# Javascript function to toggle 2 divs and change button text - tageting different ID

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have multiple groups of DIV´s with each their button, in these groups I have 2 DIVS that should toggle between them on click on that button, and also switch the content on the buttons, but each group and button have their own unique ID.

The button ID´s are defined with EditButton<%=DataCon("ID")%> (Which gives EditButton1, EditButton2, EditButton3 .. etc) and the 2 DIVS in each group is called `EditData<%=DataCon("ID")%>` and `TextData<%=DataCon("ID")%>` (I.e `EditData1` and `TextData`)

The button serverside:

```
<button id="EditButton<%=DataCon("ID")%>" class="btn btn-success" data-text-swap="<< Luk Redigering">Åben Redigering >></button>
```

Which result in:

```
<button id="EditButton1" class="btn btn-success" data-text-swap="<< Luk Redigering">Åben Redigering >></button>
```

The Severside JavaScript (ASP) I have:

```js
$(function(){
  $('div.EditData<%=DataCon("ID")%>').hide();// hide it initially
  $('button').on('click', function(){
      $('div.EditData<%=DataCon("ID")%>, div.TextData<%=DataCon("ID")%>').toggle();
  });
});

$("button.EditButton<%=DataCon("ID")%>").on("click", function() {
  var el = $(this);
  if (el.text() == el.data("text-swap")) {
    el.text(el.data("text-original"));
  } else {
    el.data("text-original", el.text());
    el.text(el.data("text-swap"));
  }
});
```

Which results in :

```
$(function(){
  $('div.EditData1').hide();// hide it initially
  $('button').on('click', function(){
      $('div.EditData1, div.TextData1').toggle();
  });
});

$("button.EditButton1").on("click", function() {
  var el = $(this);
  if (el.text() == el.data("text-swap")) {
    el.text(el.data("text-original"));
  } else {
    el.data("text-original", el.text());
    el.text(el.data("text-swap"));
  }
});
```

The Severside DIVS in HTML :

```
<div class="EditData<%=DataCon("ID")%>" style="display:none">
  <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="<%=DataCon("FullName")%>" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" style="width: 100px;">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button"><i class="far fa-save"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="TextData<%=DataCon("ID")%>">
  <%=DataCon("FullName")%>
</div>
```

Which results in:

```
<div class="EditData1" style="display:none">
  <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Some Name" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" style="width: 100px;">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button"><i class="far fa-save"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="TextData1">
  Some Name
</div>
```

The above script is obviously not working because I am not calling the DIVS and Buttons correctly, but how do I fix this?

Best Regards

Stig :-)

Comment: Forget the `id` attributes in dynamically repeated content, they cause more problems than they solve. Use common classes instead. Then relate the elements to the clicked button using DOM traversal methods such as `closest()` and `find()`. If you want a more specific example of this, please include all relevant HTML in the question. Right now the HTML is missing the `div.EditData<%=DataCon("MobileNumberToMove")%>`, `div.TextData<%=DataCon("MobileNumberToMove")%>` and `button.EditButton<%=DataCon("ID")%>` elements.

Comment: Hi Rory .. Sorry, the MobileNumberToMove was a fault, it should have been ID .. I have updated my post with more relevant and explanation. :-) .. and yes, I might need a little more specific example, please :-)

Comment: If the `button` element is hidden when the page loads, how can you click it to toggle any of the elements?

Comment: No, it is not the button that is hidden, but the DIV .. I have just updated the post with the button included,.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think @Rory McCrossan's idea to use `closest()` would work, the only issue is that if you have display none on the container with the button in it, then the button won't be visible to begin with.

You could adjust your markup a bit so that the Edit button and the form are both siblings of a common parent. That would allow you to use [`nextSibling()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) in vanilla JS, or [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) in jQuery

```js
$('.toggle').on('click', function(event) {
  $(this).next('.EditData').toggleClass('invisible');
  let text = $(this).parent().find('.TextData').toggleClass('invisible');
  let newText = $(this).text() === 'Åben Redigering >>' ? '<< Luk Redigering' : 'Åben Redigering >>';
  $(this).text(newText);
})
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button id="EditButton1" class="toggle btn btn-success" data-text-swap="<< Luk Redigering">Åben Redigering >></button>

  <div class="EditData invisible">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Some Name" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" style="width: 100px;">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button"><i class="far fa-save"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="TextData">
    Some more info should appear here below
  </div>
</div>
```

If you do it this way, you're relying on the structure of your template. You don't need to use a dynamic id to do a query each time as long as you put your button that triggers the toggle in the same position relative to one another with the same class names, this should work. Let me know if I misunderstood what you were trying to do there and I can edit my answer :)

Comment: It does some of what it should, but it is missing the second DIV that it should toggle .. another issue is that your code uses class on the button to toggle the button, that gives me an issue with CSS since if I add my css class to the class the script does not work.

Comment: something I don't get about your code though, I only see one button and it's inside of the div with display:none applied, so it won't be visible at first to enable the toggle. Unless I'm missing something

Comment: .. also inside the DIV´s I have multiple buttons that should not affect the toggle, so we need also have that in mind.

Comment: That button inside the DIV is not the button that should affect the DIV.

Comment: Okay, so you just didn't include the button that should trigger the toggle in your question? Also, not sure I understand about why using a class on the button for toggling would be an issue. You can add your classes for css and that shouldn't affect the script's ability to target the correct button. Feel free to update the code in your question to include the button that should do the toggle

Comment: I edited it 1 hour ago and included the main button : <button id="EditButton1" class="btn btn-success" data-text-swap="<< Luk Redigering">Åben Redigering >></button>

Comment: gotcha, just saw that. I've edited my answer as well to include a button. I think I see what you were saying about the css classes and that issue should be fixed now as well. You should be able to just add the toggle class to your button as long as the button and these two divs are inside of the same parent element the above code should work.

Comment: Okay, almost there, but your code opens both DIV´s at the same time, instead of open DIV1 on first click, and open DIV2 on next click.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229333/discussion-between-dakota-lee-martinez-and-stkol76).